# Redux-form Material-UI dropdown not showing dropdown, selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

Im using Material-ui select `@material-ui/core/Select` with redux-form as a HOC. I have created the form and select box appears but the options are not showing.

here is my component

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

import SelectField from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

const renderSelectField = ({
  input,
  label,
  meta: { touched, error },
  children,
  ...custom
}) => (
  <SelectField
    floatingLabelText={label}
    errorText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value)}
    children={children}
    {...custom}
  />
);

const Form = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <Field
          name="favoriteColor"
          component={renderSelectField}
          label="Favorite Color"
        >
          <MenuItem value="1" primaryText="value 1" />
          <MenuItem value="2" primaryText="value 2" />
          <MenuItem value="3" primaryText="value 3" />
        </Field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "form" 
})(Form);
```

It appears as below 
[image]
when clicked the combobox options as here
[image]

And I have created a codesandbox instance 
https://codesandbox.io/s/l2pqoryvvl?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the MenuItems to

```
  <MenuItem value="1">value 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="2">value 2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="3">value 3</MenuItem>
```

menu item does not take a primary text as a prop.

[image: Description of solution]

Answer (score 0):

@S.Haviv has mentioned when i change

`<MenuItem value="1" text="value 1" />` 
to 
`<MenuItem value='1'>value 1</MenuItem>` the menu items appeared but the click isn't success. so I had to get rid of the onclick handler in the `Select` field
and also I added a label for the component

Here is the code for complete component
https://codesandbox.io/s/l2pqoryvvl?fontsize=14

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

import SelectField from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';

const renderSelectField = ({
  input,
  label,
  meta: { touched, error },
  children,
  ...custom
}) => (
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel >{label}</InputLabel>
      <SelectField
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={touched && error}
        {...input}
        children={children}
        {...custom}
        />
    </FormControl>

  );

const Form = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <Field
          name="value"
          component={renderSelectField}
          label="Choose a Value"
          value="1"
        >
          <MenuItem value="1">value 1 </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="2">value 2 </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="3">value 3 </MenuItem>
        </Field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "form" // a unique identifier for this form
})(Form);
```